# In wxTreeListCtrl, can we extract node from tree if that node's data/text is given?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have a wxTreeListCtrl with columns name, path, size. I have constructed tree. can I retrieve a node from tree which has path="some path". Is there any function for this?

Comment: Take a look at tree traversal algorithms.

Comment: yes, but do we have any function in wxWidgets for performing this task?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no built-in function for this. You can do it yourself by iterating over the entire tree, of course, but this is not exactly very efficient.

What I'd do instead would be to have a separate `map<path,item>` in your program and construct the tree from this map -- and, if necessary, keep it updated when items are added to/deleted from the tree. For the latter, keeping a pointer to the item stored in the map as "item data" in `wxTreeCtrl` could be useful.